# microsoft visual studio installer project Post Build Event

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I am trying to create an MSI through Microsofts visual studio installer project. Everything is working fine except for my "PostBuildEvent" I am trying to modify the Userinit string located "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" in my post-build event I have

```
REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v Userinit /f

REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v Userinit /t REG_SZ /d C:\Windows\system32\MyApp.exe, /f
```

This doesn't appear to be working, Would anyone have any ideas on how I can modify this String value with the MSI?

Comment: Can you just clarify: You talk about a "PostBuildEvent" (which is run after *building* the MSI file) but it appears that you are looking for a **post install** event (to be executed after an actual installation of/by that MSI file). Or am I getting muddled up?

Comment: In the properties there is a section called "PostBuildEvent" It runs whatever you put in there during the install process. Inside of the after the Reg delete/Add I added a pause to wait for a user to press enter, and it said the code ran successfully during the test install but it never actually change the registry at all.

Comment: Well, if you're using the "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects" extension to create your MSI, then the command(s) in PostBuildEvents run(s) **after a successful build** and *not* when you run the installer. The 'caption' says, *"Specifies any commands to execute after the build ends."* In my projects, I use this to, for example, add a digital signature to the MSI file using the `SignTool` command.

Comment: To have the installer run a command after it has installed the package, you (probably) need to add a DLL to the packages and invoke a function in that via "Custom Actions". (I do just this to run - if required - the VC redistributable package.)